# Customize DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager to verify all matching rules, instead of giving up on the first that matches

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an application with a fairly complex authorization model.
In the database, I can have entries that specify authorities required for particular endpoints and I load them at the application startup.

Examples (method, pattern, authority):

1. `GET` - `/api/service1/someEntity` - `GET_SERVICE1_SOME_ENTITY_AUTHORITY`
2. `GET` - `/api/service2/someEntity` - `GET_SERVICE2_SOME_ENTITY_AUTHORITY`
3. `GET` - `/api/service1/**` - `GET_SERVICE1_ANYTHING_AUTHORITY`
4. `null` - `/**` - `DO_ANYTHING` *(admin)*

Before I load these rules, I **sort them from most specific to most general**, so they end up in exactly the same order as above. I load them like that (for each in the sorted order):

```java
http.authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers(permission.getMethod(), permission.getPattern())
    .hasAuthority(permission.getAuthority());
```

Now the problem is that when I have user: `ADMIN` with authority `DO_ANYTHING`, it will actually not be able to do anything, because of the way how spring security works.

Let's say the `admin` wants to access `/api/service1/someEntity`.
Spring will match rule no.1 and check if `admin` has authority `GET_SERVICE1_SOME_ENTITY_AUTHORITY` and it will turn out that he doesn't. At this point, Spring will deny access. But what I want it to do is to check other matching rules (numbers 3 and 4).

I found [the code responsible for this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/87828df9d53ea43053f9c0cde936bca30629da75/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/authorization/DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager.java#L52):

```java
public final class DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager implements ReactiveAuthorizationManager<ServerWebExchange> {
// ...
    @Override
    public Mono<AuthorizationDecision> check(Mono<Authentication> authentication, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(this.mappings).concatMap((mapping) -> mapping.getMatcher().matches(exchange)
                .filter(MatchResult::isMatch).map(MatchResult::getVariables).flatMap((variables) -> {
                    logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> "Checking authorization on '"
                            + exchange.getRequest().getPath().pathWithinApplication() + "' using "
                            + mapping.getEntry()));
                    return mapping.getEntry().check(authentication, new AuthorizationContext(exchange, variables));
                })).next().defaultIfEmpty(new AuthorizationDecision(false));
    }
// ...
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to replace this implementation with mine.

tldr: **I want spring security to verify all security rules matching the request path, instead of denying access on the first one that matches.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a solution, a little bit hacky, but it does what I need.

I've created my own implementation of `ReactiveAuthorizationManager<ServerWebExchange>`, which is almost the same as Spring's `DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager`, but has one additional filter, which does the job:

```java
public class MyAuthorizationManager implements ReactiveAuthorizationManager<ServerWebExchange> {

    private final List<ServerWebExchangeMatcherEntry<ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext>>> mappings;

    @Override
    public Mono<AuthorizationDecision> check(Mono<Authentication> authentication, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(this.mappings)
                   .concatMap((mapping) -> mapping.getMatcher()
                                                  .matches(exchange)
                                                  .filter(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult::isMatch)
                                                  .map(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult::getVariables)
                                                  .flatMap((variables) -> {
                                                      log.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> "Checking authorization on '"
                                                              + exchange.getRequest()
                                                                        .getPath()
                                                                        .pathWithinApplication() + "' using "
                                                              + mapping.getEntry()).toString());
                                                      return mapping.getEntry()
                                                                    .check(authentication, new AuthorizationContext(exchange, variables));
                                                  }).filter(AuthorizationDecision::isGranted) /* <- this is what I needed */)
                   .next()
                   .defaultIfEmpty(new AuthorizationDecision(false));
    }
}
```

and this is how I registered it:

```java
 @Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        
        List<Permission> permissions = repo.getPermissions()

        MyAuthorizationManager.Builder authBuilder = MyAuthorizationManager.builder();

        permissions.forEach(permission -> {
            // I create the mappings here, so matcher + auth manager for that matcher
            authBuilder.add(
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(permission.getMethod(), permission.getPattern()), 
                    AuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority(permission.getAuthority())
            );
        });
        
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .anonymous().disable();

        // it will be before the default authorization filter, bu actually it doesn't really matter
        http.addFilterBefore(new AuthorizationWebFilter(authBuilder.build()), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);

        return http.build();
}
```

I have left `.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll()` because it sets some default things like entry point, exception web filter and I didn't want to copy more code and totally give up the default manager.